# python regex: extract a string between 2 values without including patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
a="12cdanfaw3i8hanjwofaef56ghah398hafadsf12cds;dkh38hfasdf56ghaldkshf12cdasdiuhf93f2asdf56gh"
```

I'm trying to extract a string between `12cd` and `56gh`. Those values would be `anfaw3i8hanjwofaef`, `s;dkh38hfasdf`, `asdiuhf93f2asdf`

The regex that I have is `re.findall(r'12cd.*56gh', a)`.

But the patterns are included in the output.

How do I write the regex to not include it in the output?

Thanks

Comment: How does Python deal with regex captures? `r'12cd(.*)56gh'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a non-greedy regex to get all 3 matches, and you also need to use a matching group to not include the pattern, so use `12cd(.*?)56gh`

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'12cd(.*?)56gh', '12cdanfaw3i8hanjwofaef56ghah398hafadsf12cds;dkh38hfasdf56ghaldkshf12cdasdiuhf93f2asdf56gh'))
```

Output:

```
['anfaw3i8hanjwofaef', 's;dkh38hfasdf', 'asdiuhf93f2asdf']
```

Explanation

```
12cd              // matches 12cd
    (             // matching group 1
      .*?         // matches any character between 0 and unlimited times, lazy
    )             
56gh              // matches 56gh
```

Comment: What does ? do?

Comment: `*?` will match between 0 and unlimited times, but match as few times as possible, expanding as necessary.